# serializer only certain fields in foreing key relation

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to serializer two nested models linked by a foreing key:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    sp = models.ForeignKey('species.Sp', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='species_category')
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Catch(models.Model):
    weight = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('species.Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
```

I know is possible to use `depth` option, but it serialize all the fields of the related model, for example:

```
class CatchesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Catch
        fields = ['id', 'weight', 'category', ]
        depth = 1
```

returns

```
[
    {
        "id": 335,
        "weight": 4710,
        "category": {
            "id": 1,
            "category_name": "1",
            "sp": 41
        }
    },
...
]
```

How is the way to serialize only certains fields of the related model? for example:

```
[
    {
        "id": 335,
        "weight": 4710,
        "category": {
            "sp": 41,
        }
    },
...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializer can be **[`nested`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)**, you can try:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['sp']

class CatchesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Catch
        fields = ['id', 'weight', 'category']
```